# elasticsearch 5: returning same document multiple times if multiple array items of one document fit condition

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

We are using elastic search 5 (yes I know it is EOL but it is what it is)

Elastic newbie here with a rather complicated task:

Let's imagine we have an event index filled with multiple event documents. Those event documents might have n speakers attached in a `speakers` object array. A speaker has a `gender` attribute.

How can I achieve the following query?
"return event for each speaker whose gender is `x` "

## returning query result:

```json
{
 page: 1,
 pageSize: 20,
 total: 3
 items: [
  {
   id: 1,
   speakers: [
    {
     name: 'Sascha',
     gender: 'x'
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   id: 1,
   speakers: [
    {
     name: 'Leo',
     gender: 'x'
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   id: 2,
   speakers: [
    {
     name: 'Rue',
     gender: 'x'
    }
   ]
  },
 ]
}
```

## event index filled with three event documents

**event 1**

```json
{
  id: 1,
  speakers: [
   {
    name: 'Sascha',
    gender: 'x'
   },
   {
    name: 'Leo',
    gender: 'x'
   },
  ]
}
```

**event 2**

```json
{
  id: 2,
  speakers: [
   {
    name: 'Thomas',
    gender: 'm'
   },
   {
    name: 'Rue',
    gender: 'x'
   },
  ]
}
```

**event 3**

```json
{
  id: 2,
  speakers: [
   {
    name: 'Nicole',
    gender: 'f'
   }
  ]
}
```

I didn't even start to code or write a query because I am not sure if elastic is built to give me a result like the one I want to achieve.

I don't even know how to articulate the type of query I am trying to achieve :/
Or do I have to create a new index which combines event and speaker index in a way I can work with?

Comment: you want apply paging in items speakers? I believe isn't possible.

Comment: @rabbitbr it would be nice if it worked with pagination, its not a must. We are currently reading into nested queries. Maybe this is the right way.

Comment: you can to use nested query with inner_hits. Inner Hists return the elements matches.

Comment: fyi: we decided to implement a seperate index for this search. we tried to find another work around but our feature requester wants pagination and sorting implemented, so this is the only way of solving this!